# Permanently apply a rotation

Tags: animation

I want to scale an object in the world axis when the object rotates.
But for not scaling the object in his own axis but in world axis we need first to apply his rotation. So I don't succeed to do both things in the same time.

Answer (score 5):

You can parent the object to an empty, scale the empty along the world axes, and rotate the object around its local axes.

In the example below, the empty is the parent of the cube, the empty changes scale, and the cube rotates around its local axis

[image: rotate-scale]

Comment: Sorry. I use animation nodes and your method work if I scale the empty before then rotate the object but not both il the same time.